# How do I install scipy & its optimization module (using Python 2.7.10)

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I've run the following optimization example code (and alternatives) and it keeps giving me the following error(s) --

> "Input Error: cannot import optimize" OR "No module named optimize"

```
import numpy as np

from scipy import optimize

from scipy.optimize import fmin_slsqp

def f(x): return np.sqrt((x[0] - 3)**2 + (x[1] - 2)**2)

def constraint(x):
        return np.atleast_1d(1.5 - np.sum(np.abs(x)))

scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp(f, np.array([0,0]), ieqcons = [constraint,])
```

I've also tried to update Scipy and Optimize with the pip command.  Scipy is updated and I get the following when trying to update Optimize:

"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement optimize (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for optimize"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check scipy is really installed? Do `pip list` and see if scipy is installed or not?

Comment: @ankur, yes it is installed.  scipy (0.15.1) was returned

Comment: How did you install it? Are you sure pip is connected to the same python-environment which you are calling? Which OS? If windows, i **highly recommend** [the anaconda distribution](https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda) which is even recommend (among others) by scipy themself! If Linux, then there is probably a binary-package for a modern scipy-version!

Comment: @Sascha , how do I determine if I'm calling the right python environment?  Also, I'm currently stuck using python xy.

Comment: @Roman A non-clean, but easy approach: just install something from pip, which you know, is not installed yet. Than import within your python interpreter. I don't think it's the source of the origin, but it's possible. But i'm still puzzled about your problem. Why not remove everything and install python xy from scratch (i can't imagine why scipy should fail after clean install). And why use python xy? These packages are quite old! And while it's probably not the problem here: don't mix python xy with other binary installers/sources!

Comment: This will be lengthy, but I get the following error:  C:\Users\Roman>easy_install C:\Users\Roman\Downloads\scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
Processing scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
Writing c:\users\roman\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-fafkgi\scipy\setup.cfg Running scipy\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\roman\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-fafkgi\scipy\egg-dist-tmp-dh4wxw C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:642: UserWarning: Specified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/ia32 is invalid.

Comment: Also says "Atlas libraries not found"

Comment: You post an error but didnt tell us what you tried. And also you didn't react to suggestions i gave :-). I assume you tried to install scipy. Well... from sources (indicated by the need for atlas) it's (very) impossible on windows; from a binary: well... it's invalidating the rule i gave above (if it's not a whl from python xy)! Just remove everything and install **the whole python xy** from scratch or better: use anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Can you upgrade `scipy` to version 0.17?  I can't reproduce the error with version 0.17:

`pip install scipy==0.17.0`

Comment: for some reason, it won't let me upgrade to 0.17.  I even tried 0.18.0.  It fails to build wheels for scipy and fails to clean build dir for scipy.

Comment: try `easy_install scipy`

Comment: Got the following - 

Searching for scipy
Best match: scipy 0.15.1
Adding scipy 0.15.1 to easy-install.pth file

Comment: Weird, I return "Best match: scipy 0.17.0".  Well, you can download the local scipy files from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy and then use easy_install: `easy_install <absolute_path_to_download_file>`

Comment: Now, I have scipy 18.0, but code still doesn't work.  Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: No problem, I need to boost my points!  I am beginning to think one of the underlying requirements for scipy is not working on your machine.  Would you be open to re-installing scipy via a comprehensive package?  For example: http://www.scipy.org/install.html#scientific-python-distributions

Comment: Nick, I'm up for anything.  I already tried using the package you provided.  I downloaded scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl.  Sorry, but i'm not 100% sure if that was even the right download.  I checked my python xy version, and it said 32bit so I figured that would be the scipy version I would need.  I could be wrong.

Comment: yeah, that sounds like the correct file.  So use `easy_install <path_to_download_file>` to install that package.  Let me know what you get